# Determing type of template parameter in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am working on a C++ project and attempting to make use of templating functions for the first time. I understand the basic gist of how you might use templates but I need to know what data type the variable is so I can perform a specific action.

For example, my method is defined as follows:

```
template<typename T> void increment(T data);
```

I need to check what type of data the variable data contains. For example, I want to be able to do following pseudo code

```
template <typename T> void MyClass::increment(std::string stats, T tags)
{
   if (tags of_type std::string)
   {
      //Perform some string manipulation
   }
   else if (tags of_type std::vector)
   {
      //Extract each string from the vector
   }
   else
   {
      //only strings or vectors are supported
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of function overloading?

Comment: Yes of course I know that you can do that, but for my project that it would involve lots of different variations of the same method, for several different methods, I was hoping to avoid that, as if the above is possible, it will be clearer, non repetitive code

Comment: Usually, overloading is the best approach.  If the methods are generally similar apart from a few lines that depend on the type, the best plan is to isolate those few lines into a method with overloads, and call that from your bigger template function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

struct MyClass {
    template <typename T>
    void increment(std::string stats, T tags);
};


template <typename T>
void MyClass::increment(std::string stats, T tags)
{
    if (std::is_same<T,std::string>::value)
    {
        //Perform some string manipulation
    }
    else if (std::is_same<T,std::vector<std::string>>::value)
    {
        //Extract each string from the vector
    }
    else
    {
        //only strings or vectors are supported
    }
}
```

You definitely should prefer overloading but if you do not want to repeat the function declaration in the class body and also do not want to inline the function in the class, you could use explicit specialization with a deleted primary template.  This will trigger a compiler error if the function is not implemented for this type.

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

struct MyClass {
    template <typename T>
    void increment(std::string stats, T tags) = delete;
};

template <>
void MyClass::increment(std::string stats, std::string tags)
{
    //Perform some string manipulation
}

template <>
void MyClass::increment(std::string stats, std::vector<std::string> tags)
{
    //Extract each string from the vector
}

int main() {
    MyClass{}.increment(std::string{}, std::string{});
    MyClass{}.increment(std::string{}, std::vector<std::string>{});
    MyClass{}.increment(std::string{}, int{}); // BOOM!
}
```

Comment: This "switch on type" is considered an anti-pattern and should be discouraged.

Comment: I did end up going for the function overloading in the end, my main problem was each method had several optional parameters as well, as well as variables being of different data types, so I would have had to create loads of functions for each variation, except I didn't realise c++ actually supports default parameter values (e.g. `void myFunc(int i, int j = 0);` so that removes my problem with creating overriding methods

Answer (score 2):

As [Henri Menke hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255101/determing-type-of-template-parameter-in-c/48255128#comment83492908_48255101), what you need to use here is not templates, but function overloading. A template does not fit this use case too much, since templated code is meant to be as generic as possible - and your requirement of branching on types makes it non-generic.

Just overload those functions:

```
// In reality, you may want to pass both by reference 
// (depends if you mutate those local variables
// in your function or not)
void MyClass::increment(std::string stats, std::string tags)
{
   //Perform some string manipulation
}

void MyClass::increment(std::string stats, std::vector<std::string> tags)
{
    //Extract each string from the vector
}
```

EDIT:
In a comment you said you want to keep it as a single function for readability - however, I'd say this is a personal preference and I'd advise not doing that. Otherwise, if your function becomes too complex you might have issues following which branches are "type based" and which are actual code flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly specialize a function template if the main template is insufficient for some reason (or simply provide a regular overload, that will be picked before a template in the resolution process).

```
template<typename T> void increment(T & value) { ++value; }

void increment(MyClass & value) { value.Increment(); }
```

If the parameter you pass is a MyClass lvalue then the latter will be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know what data type the variable is so I can perform a specific action.

To know the data type you can use type traits; standard type traits as `std::is_same`

```
 if ( std::is_same<T, std::string>::value )
```

or custom self-made type traits

```
 template <typename>
 struct isVect : public std::false_type
  { };

 template <typename ... Ts>
 struct isVect<std::vector<Ts...>> : public std::true_type
  { };

 // ....

 if ( isVect<T>::value )
```

But

```
 if ( std::is_same<T, std::string>::value )
  { /* some code 1 */ }
 else if ( isVect<T>::value )
  { /* some code 2 */ }
 else
  { /* some code 3 */ }
```

is (generally speaking) a bad idea.

All goes well if "some code x" contain code that can be executed independently from the type `T` (say the log, through `std::cout`, of a literal string).

But if, by example, "some code 2" contains specific `std::vector` instructions, calling the function with a `std::string` you get an error. Because the "some code 2" part isn't executed when `T` is a `std::string` but the compiler compile it.

This problem can be solved starting from C++17 that introduce `if constexpr`

```
 if constexpr ( std::is_same<T, std::string>::value )
  { /* compiled only in std::string case */ }
 else if constexpr ( isVect<T>::value )
  { /* compiled only in std::vector case */ }
 else
  { /* compiled only in other cases */ }
```

But for C++11 and C++14 the best I can suggest is the use of overloading

```
void MyClass::increment (std::string stats, std::string s)
 { /* string manipulation */ }

template <typename T>
void MyClass::increment (std::string stats, std::vector<T> v)
 { /* string from vector */ }

template <typename T>
void MyClass::increment (std::string stats, T t)
 { /* no std::string and no std::vector */ }
```

or, if there is a lot of common code in `increment()`, demand the different parts to helper functions

```
void MyClass::increment_helper (std::string s)
 { /* string manipulation */ }

template <typename T>
void MyClass::increment_helper (std::vector<T> v)
 { /* string from vector */ }

template <typename T>
void MyClass::increment_helper (T t)
 { /* no std::string and no std::vector */ }

template <typename T>
void MyClass::increment (std::string stats, T t)
 {
   /* common code */

   increment_helper(t);

   /* other common code */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In c++17, you might use `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename T>
void MyClass::increment(std::string stats, T tags)
{
   if constexpr (std::is_same<std::string, T>::value)
   {
      //Perform some string manipulation
   }
   else if constexpr (std::is_same<std::vector<std::string>, T>::value)
   {
      //Extract each string from the vector
   }
   else
   {
      static_assert(false, "only strings or vectors are supported");
   }
}
```

Without `if constexpr`, if you use that method, you might have compilation error in the "false branches" as code should be valid for types used.

In your case, overload is the best btw:

```
void MyClass::increment(std::string stats, const std::string& tags)
{
    //Perform some string manipulation
}

void MyClass::increment(std::string stats, const std::vector<std::string>& tags)
{
    //Extract each string from the vector
}
```